# How can I set __package__ of a script from within an imported library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, inspect

The `__package__` attribute can be set to allow directly executing a python script that is also part of a module (e.g. uses relative imports). Without `__package__`, one can only run it as `python3 -m parent.child.script` but with `__package__ = 'child'`, one can also run more easily as `python3 script.py`.

From [PEP 366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/):

> When the main module is specified by its filename, then the **package** attribute will be set to None. To allow relative imports when the module is executed directly, boilerplate similar to the following would be needed before the first relative import statement:
>
> ```
> if __name__ == "__main__" and __package__ is None:
>     __package__ = "expected.package.name"
> ```
>
> Note that this boilerplate is sufficient only if the top level package is already accessible via sys.path. Additional code that manipulates sys.path would be needed in order for direct execution to work without the top level package already being importable.

I'm trying to move this boilerplate into a library that each script can import. I already have code available to import the package, resulting in this boilerplate snippet:

```py
import pathlib, imptools
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ == None:
  __package__ = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.name
  imptools.import_from_path(__package__, '..')
```

Now I would like to simplify this to the following, which requires setting `__package__` for the script from within the library rather than the script itself.

```py
import relative_import
relative_import.enable()
```

I know how to find out what script file the library function is called from. This can be done via `inspect`:

```py
import inspect
for info in inspect.stack():
  if info.filename == __file__:
    continue
  break
script = info.filename
```

The only problem left is, how can I set `__package__` of the script module from within the library?

Comment: 2c: this seems like a bad idea and you should just use `python -m` -- running as a script has other (bad) consequences on `sys.path` (notably for `python path/to/script.py` it puts `path/to` on the beginning of `sys.path` which *will* burn you at some point)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Thanks for the disclaimer. I just want to make my code easy to run for users. `python -m` requires the user to be in exactly the right directory, which is a common failure case. I'm not too worried about long-term maintenance because this is for a research project that will not change much in the future (and will likely be replaced by something better in a few years).

Comment: Other things that will bite you: Your code seems to implicitly assume the calling script is directly under a top-level package, instead of being part of a subpackage. Also, if `pathimp` is that thing you mentioned in your earlier answer, `pathimp.import_module` is going to unconditionally try to create a new package object even if the package object already exists, which could happen if multiple modules use this `relative_import.enable()` thing, or if someone knows about and uses `python -m`.

Comment: Good point, I've added the correct guard to the example: `if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ == None:`. The current code works regardless of whether it is run as `python3 script.py` or `python3 -m child.script`.  I agree that in may cases, running as module is the way to go but there are also uses for `__package__` as laid out in PEP 366. Do you think it is possible to hide this boilerplate in a library?

Comment: For context, I renamed `pathimp` to `imptools` to contain both import helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do something very finicky here, but this part, at least, is easy. The script module is always `__main__`. You can just `import __main__` and set `__main__.__package__`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

I've created the [imptools](https://github.com/danijar/imptools) package to easily enable relative imports for scripts inside modules:

```py
import imptools  # pip3 install imptools

imptools.enable_relative()

# Relative imports...
```

The script can be run either as `python3 -m module.script` or as `python3 script.py` from any directory.